# How to solve Java "Nested Loops" problem?

Tags: java

I want help in solving this problem: I want after run the program get this output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOFaH.png)

and this is code:

```
    System.out.println("n\tn^2\tn^3\tn^4");
    System.out.println("----------------");

    for (int i=1; i<5;i++)
    {
        for (int j= 1; j<4; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(Math.pow(i,j)+"\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I don’t know what is wrong with me

Answer (score 1):

the Math.pow return double and you need to cast it to int and you need to change the start number one more because the break loop immediately after the for loop condition is false not after the block execute.

```
        
    System.out.println("n\tn^2\tn^3\tn^4");
    System.out.println("----------------");

    for (int i=1; i<6;i++)
    {
        for (int j= 1; j<5; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(((int)Math.pow(i,j)+"\t"));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your help.....